# Oracle DBMS_SCHEDULE to run at 8am, 12pm, 4pm and 8pm every day of the week

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g, dbms-scheduler

I am unsure how to tackle using Oracle DBMS_SCHEDULER. I have been asked to run a particular PL/SQL procedure job at:

```
8AM, 12PM, 4PM and lastly at 8PM every day of the week
```

and then re-start again the following day at the same times again at: `8AM, 12PM, 4PM and lastly at 8PM`.

I understand that I firstly need to create a schedule but don’t know what the frequency setup should be, i.e.:

```
dbms_scheduler.create_schedule( schedule_name   => 'MY_JOB',
                                repeat_interval => 'FREQ=DAILY;BYHOUR=8;BYMINUTE=00'
                                start_date      => SYSTIMESTAMP
                              );
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't have to create a named SCHEDULE (but you can do if you prefer), you can put the repeat interval directly in the job:

```
DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_JOB (
   job_name        => ...
  ,start_date      => SYSTIMESTAMP
  ,repeat_interval => 'FREQ=HOURLY;INTERVAL=1;BYHOUR=08,12,16,20;BYMINUTE=00'
```

Note, for jobs with frequency less than daily you have to consider daylight saving times. Time zone of `SYSTIMESTAMP` is the time zone of database server's operating system, very often this is set as static UTC offset (e.g. `+02:00`). In order to take daylight saving times into account this UTC offset changes twice a year.

If jobs must follow daylight savings adjustments, then you must specify a region name for the time zone of the `start_date`. For example you can do

```
DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_JOB (
   job_name        => ...
  ,start_date      => SYSTIMESTAMP AT TIME ZONE 'Europe/Zurich'
  ,repeat_interval => 'FREQ=HOURLY;INTERVAL=1;BYHOUR=08,12,16,20;BYMINUTE=00'
```

Have a look at this PL/SQL block to see the difference.

```
DECLARE
   next_run_date TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE;
   start_date TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE; 
BEGIN
   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Static UTC offset:');
   start_date := TIMESTAMP '2019-10-26 00:00:00 +02:00';
   FOR i IN 1..10 LOOP
      DBMS_SCHEDULER.EVALUATE_CALENDAR_STRING('FREQ=HOURLY;INTERVAL=1;BYHOUR=08,12,16,20;BYMINUTE=00', start_date, next_run_date, next_run_date);
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(next_run_date AT LOCAL);
   END LOOP;

   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Time zone region name:');
    next_run_date := NULL;
   start_date := TIMESTAMP '2019-10-26 00:00:00 Europe/Zurich';
   FOR i IN 1..10 LOOP
      DBMS_SCHEDULER.EVALUATE_CALENDAR_STRING('FREQ=HOURLY;INTERVAL=1;BYHOUR=08,12,16,20;BYMINUTE=00', start_date, next_run_date, next_run_date);
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(next_run_date AT LOCAL);
   END LOOP;

END;

Static UTC offset:
2019-10-26 08:00:00.000 +02:00
2019-10-26 12:00:00.000 +02:00
2019-10-26 16:00:00.000 +02:00
2019-10-26 20:00:00.000 +02:00
2019-10-27 07:00:00.000 +01:00
2019-10-27 11:00:00.000 +01:00
2019-10-27 15:00:00.000 +01:00
2019-10-27 19:00:00.000 +01:00
2019-10-28 07:00:00.000 +01:00
2019-10-28 11:00:00.000 +01:00

Time zone region name:
2019-10-26 08:00:00.000 +02:00
2019-10-26 12:00:00.000 +02:00
2019-10-26 16:00:00.000 +02:00
2019-10-26 20:00:00.000 +02:00
2019-10-27 08:00:00.000 +01:00
2019-10-27 12:00:00.000 +01:00
2019-10-27 16:00:00.000 +01:00
2019-10-27 20:00:00.000 +01:00
2019-10-28 08:00:00.000 +01:00
2019-10-28 12:00:00.000 +01:00
```

See [Repeat Intervals and Daylight Savings](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADMIN/scheduse.htm#ADMIN10020) for more details

Comment: Is there any option to for more than 1 upvote? 100s upvotes on this from my side.

Comment: I know about bounites, But I can only give them to you if I have asked this question. I meant to say i liked your answer too much but i cannot do anything apart from just an upvote.

Comment: @AnkitBajpai: anyone can give a bounty, as long as they have enough rep, and two days have passed. You are welcome to add bounties to other people's questions.

Comment: Still looking through your response @WernfriedDomscheit but wanted to ask, what would be required if I wanted to pause this scheduled job as well as restart this paused job again?

Comment: @tonyf, you can use `DBMS_SCHEDULER.DISABLE` and `DBMS_SCHEDULER.ENABLE`